# Cartesian Planner Plugin not selectable on RViz

Tags: ros-hydro, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following [its wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_cartesian_plan_plugin#Run_for_the_first_Time) I opened a plugin list in a trial to add `Cartesian Path Planner MoveIt Plugin` after running:

```
roslaunch motoman_sia20d_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch
```

I don't see the plugin in the list.

`rospack find moveit_cartesian_plan_plugin` seems to be returning the right path to the package.

Anything missing am I?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204089/cartesian-planner-plugin-not-selectable-on-rviz/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2015-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just figured out. [Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_cartesian_plan_plugin#Run_for_the_first_Time) wasn't correct.

```
roslaunch fermi_sia20d_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0